# Can prime ng p-datatable p-column use responsive classes ui-grid-col

Tags: responsive-design, primeng-datatable

I want to use responsive column widths for my p-datatable p-columns like so:

```
<p-dataTable [class]="'ui-grid ui-grid-responsive ui-grid-pad'" 
  [value]="dataList" [responsive]="true" [paginator]="true" [rows]="10" 
  [rowsPerPageOptions]="[10,25,50,100]" emptyMessage="Nothing to see 
  here...">
  <p-column [class]="'ui-grid-col-1'" field="ID" header="ID" ></p-column>
  <p-column [class]="'ui-grid-col-2'" field="Title"  header="Title">
  </p-column>
  <p-column [class]="'ui-grid-col-4'" field="Desc"  header="Description">
  </p-column>
</p-dataTable>
```

Also, I would to apply different classes for grid columns based on display width breakpoints (-sm, -md, -lg) like Bootstrap.
Can this be done?